# importing tweets to csv file using Python

Tags: python, twitter

I would like to import tweets and date posted from specific person's Twitter account into a CSV file using Python. I get all data but date goes to underneath (next row) of twitter post instead of next column. I want twitter post in first column and date posted in next column. Could you please help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write your own csv reader and writer.

Have you tried just using python's built-in module?
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```